# Can't fix this ffmpeg, NoClassDefFoundError org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil

Tags: java, ffmpeg, java-8

I am trying to get the video duration with this library `import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;`

When I upload this mp4 video (https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4), I get this error message:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil`

It will break when trying to get the 'grabber':

```java
private void videoInfo(MultipartFile file) {
    try (FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(file.getInputStream())) { // on this line it will break :(
        grabber.start();
        long durationMs = grabber.getLengthInTime();
    } catch (FrameGrabber.Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.9'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.nob234'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.9'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    // for logging
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.30'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.30'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
    implementation 'org.bytedeco:javacv:1.5.8'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

This is my ffmpeg version:

```
ffmpeg version 6.0-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
```

Please keep in mind that I use Java 8 in this project and I hope this issue is reproducible. If you want more info please leave a comment.

Comment: Please provide the full exception stacktrace. The "Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil" suggests that something went wrong while loading the class, the details of that are likely deeper in the exception stacktrace.

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://pastebin.com/2vicmTnr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a dependency to the jar containing `org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil`

Replace

```
implementation 'org.bytedeco:javacv:1.5.8'
```

With

```
implementation 'org.bytedeco:javacv-platform:1.5.8'
```

See [bytedeco downloads page](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/#downloads)

Comment: I get this

> Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.
   > Name must not be null!

**You can see the full log here:** https://pastebin.com/JP0pGHNV

Comment: Sorry, typo. Fixed answer.

Comment: Unfortunatley, I have the same issue. I cleaned the project and refresh dependencies. Maybe it will help if I send you the whole stacktrace. **Here it is:** https://pastebin.com/2vicmTnr

Comment: Updated answer. Please try again.

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me how did you figure it out? AmI right that you just searched in the mvnrepository.com? I always get confused a little bit with dependencies.

Comment: A Google search of the missing full class name usually hits a dependency in mavenreposity. However, in this case that was not enough. I found the bytedeco installs page that had the right dependency

Comment: Please add “ org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil” to the end of the question title.